# How to remove string quotes in MySQL 5.7 for function JSON_EXTRACT?

Tags: mysql-5.7, json

Other than doing string manipulation after each `JSON_EXTRACT`, is there a simpler or more correct way to have the `JSON_EXTRACT` return the string WITHOUT the enclosing quotes?

Or should this question be on StachExchange?

Comment: Did you put an extra pair of quotes on the string as it was inserted??

Comment: The JSON from the REST call is a simple:
{"key": "value to return" }

Looks like the only way is to do a TRIM(BOTH " variable) <something like that ;) >

Comment: Read more on JSON_UNQUOTE here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you have MySQL 5.7.13 or later, you may use `JSON_UNQUOTE()` instead of `JSON_EXTRACT()` or `->>` instead of `->`. Example:

`SELECT field->>"$.foo.barr" FROM table;`

Comment: A much nicer syntax, I'm glad you answered that way.

Answer (score 15):

I can't comment on Alex Markov's answer because I don't have enough reputation. In my case using JSON_UNQUOTE instead of JSON_EXTRACT doesn't work, but I can get the result by wrapping the second inside the former, like this: JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(bla bla))

Comment: That's what I did in my case too.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR()` and it's working fine to unquote the string.

You can try this example:

```
SELECT emp_name,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(address,'$[1].city_name') AS city
FROM emp_details
```

Comment: This is not a valid function for MySQL 5.7 (or any other current version).